# Vue 3 + Vite + Typescript + Vuetify 3 - Struggling to enable custom scss vuetify variables

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuetify.js, vite

I'm struggling with custom variables.scss in Vuetify. I'd like to be able to edit current settings. I've added all my code into stackblitz.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-f8eyba?file=src/sass/variables.scss

I've been looking at Vuetify documentation but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.
Can somebody help, please?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install [`vite-plugin-vuetify`](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify-loader/tree/next/packages/vite-plugin) to support custom SCSS variables.